# Second order homogeneous ODE with a variable coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested whether the following ODE:  $y''(x)+y'(x)-(2+4f(x))y(x)=0$, with $f(\infty)=0$ and $f(0)=\mathcal{O}(x)$ has any solutions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the second term really $y$ or a missed prime in $y'$?

Comment: Where exactly do you see the difficulties? General theory of linear ODE says that you have a global solution if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @LutzL Sorry about the mistake,  the second term, should be $y'$. Does the comment about the existence of a global solution still apply? Sorry for my ignorance I am not a mathematician, and my knowledge about the general theory of ODE's is quite limited.

Comment: Yes, as said that is in general true for linear ODE or systems thereof with continuous coefficients. The solution exists and is unique as long as the coefficients are continuous.

Comment: @LutzL Thank you for the answer. Could you recommend any books where I can find that theorem/statement?